# Inequality involving zero-crossings of Difference of Gaussian and Laplacian of Gaussian

Tags: convolution, difference-of-gaussians

I am stuck on the following problem:

Let $f$ be a smooth real  function with a single inflection point and let $\sigma_1>\sigma_2>0$ be two real numbers. We denote $G_1$ and $G_2$ the associated Gaussian function (**see NB**). We know then that these 3 functions:

- $f''*G_1$ (Laplacian of Gaussian with $\sigma_1$)
- $f''*G_2$ (Laplacian of Gaussian with $\sigma_2$)
- $f*(G_1-G_2)$ (Difference of Gaussian with $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$)

have only one zero-crossings on $\mathbb{R}$ denoted respectively $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_{1,2}$. The problem is then, how can one show that we have the inequality:

$$\min(x_1,x_2)\leq x_{1,2}\leq\max(x_1,x_2).$$

I am really convinced that this inequality is true (numerically). Any hints will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

*NB: For $i=1,2$, the functions $G_i$ are defined by:*
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, G_i(x) \triangleq\frac{1}{\sigma_i\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(s-x)^2}{2\sigma_i^2}}$$

Comment: It would be helpful if you _edited_ your question to specify bin more detail exactly what you mean by Gaussian function.  -1 and a vote to close if you answer by _responding_ to this comment by writing a _comment_ in response to this query instead of _editiing_ your questions to include this information. You can edit your question by clicking on the `Edit` link just below your question.